# Group Like hostnames and add a counter

Tags: bash, scripting

So, I have a problem and I am not sure how to solve it.

I have a list of hostnames that are similar, but have subtle differences. For example:

```
 hostname1000
 hostname1001
 hostname1002
 hostname1003
 hostname1004
 hostname2000
 hostname2001
 hostname2002
```

I would like to group these hostnames as follows:

```
 hostname[1000-1004,2000-2002]
```

This would be for use with pdsh.

I tried the following, but it just adds a count to the end of the file name and does not group by uniq count per hostname.

```
 num=1;for a in $(cat range_hostname |cut -c 1-12 |sort) ; do echo ${a}${num}; num=$[num+1 ];done
```

Any ideas would be helpful :)

Thanks!
Joe

Answer (score 0):

So I also posted on unix.com and here is the solution to the problem so others can see:

```
 awk '
            {HN = $1
             sub (/[0-9]*$/, _, HN)
             sub (/^[a-z]*/, _, $1)
            }
NR == 1         {printf "%s[%04d-", HN, $1
            }
NR > 1 &&
$1+0 != LAST+1    {printf "%04d,%04d-", LAST, $1
            }
            {LAST = $1
            }
END             {printf "%04d]\n", $1
            }
' filename
```

filename contains a list of hostnames one line at a time.

This also assumes a group of 4 digits after the hostname as in

```
hostnmae0101
hostname0102
hostname0103 ... etc
```

The output will be

```
hostname[0101-0103]
```

Thanks!
Joe